# Database for users to select needed supplies and send an order

Tags: ms-access, checkbox, vba

Here’s what I’m working with. Most of the people that will use this database will only see the Search form (has a query subform of the total list of supplies). What I want them to be able to do is…. Perform a search for the supplies they need. Select the supplies somehow (currently this done with a checkbox). They will press a command button that will open an Order form (currently it has a query subform that only shows the supplies that were selected). From there they should press the send button to send an email with the supplies attached as an excel document to the appropriate email address. I can get some of this to work but not all. The biggest problem I have is once they select the request button I would like for all the checkboxes to return to false. I don’t know if I should use the checkboxes or if there is a better way to do this. If so, then how else could I get them to select the supplies they need. Any help or suggestions would be great because I am completely stuck on this. If I could attach my database I would so you could see it all and hopefully understand what I’m going for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your specific question, you should use a loop to reset your checkboxes.

```
Dim ctl As Control
For Each ctl In Me.Controls
    If ctl.ControlType = acCheckBox Then
        If ctl.Value <> False Then
            ctl.Value = False
        End If
    End If
Next ctl
```

As for the rest of it, please come back with *specific* questions, including any code that you've tried.  Note that this is not a free coding service, it's a website of people much like yourself helping each other.  This specific code piece was easy, but if the answer takes me more than 20 minutes I'm going to move on.  I've got my own work I have to get done!  :o)

Comment: I am sorry that my post wasn't clear enough. My biggest issue was with the checkboxes. If the code above solves that problem then all my problems are fixed. I've been stuck on this for a few days and just needed a little guidance. Thank you for taking the time out to help. I really appreciate it.